# Can Photoshop remember the colors I previously used?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, colors, gimp

I'm using Photoshop Elements 7, and I'm looking for something like what's in GIMP's color picker, where you can easily select any of the last 10 colors you used before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Photoshop Elements works the same as Photoshop with regards to the colour swatches palette.  [Here are some instructions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/PhotoshopElements/7.0_Win/WS55855988-9F73-44f1-8AA7-257420200A45.html) on how to use it.